# Jquery, hover and show the right div

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm working on a tooltip sort of thing on jquery and I just cant figure out how to minimize the coding.

```
$("#rightc img:first").hover(
 function () {
     $("ul #first").show();
  }, 
  function () {
     $("ul #first").hide();
  }
);
```

When you hover the first img you see the list item with id first.
Now when I want to add a second, for the second img I have to duplicate the whole code and it will be a lot of code and not really simple. Is there any simpler way to do this?

Comment: please post your related HTML codes to,,

Comment: Four upvotes in two minutes for this??

Comment: I'll get a jsfiddle up in a second.

Comment: Consider using CSS selectors instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just make a function that accepts the img and the div you have associated with it. Something like what i have below.

```
tooltipHover = function(img,div){
     $(img).hover(
      function () {
          $(div).show();
       }, 
       function () {
          $(div).hide();
       }
     );
};

tooltipHover("#rightc img:first","ul #first");
```

Comment: Thank you, that minimize the function pretty much. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 1):

add a data attributes to your img with the associated id of ul that you want to show/hide... 
and use `data()`.

try this

```
<img src=".." data-ulID="first" />
<img src=".." data-ulID="second" />


 $("#rightc img").hover(
   function () {
     var id=$(this).data('ulID');
     $("ul #"+id).show();
   }, 
  function () {
    var id=$(this).data('ulID');
    $("ul #"+id).hide();
  }
 );
```